# Rails AJAX to controller method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm trying to get a Rails form I made to:

1. post to a controller method,
2. run a command,
3. save the results to a variable,
4. and display them in a `div` on the same page.

I've gotten everything to work so far except the last step.  Going through some AJAX tutorials, I'm not sure what I've done wrong or am missing now.

**tools_controller.rb**

```html
  def ping
    ip = params[:ip]
    tool_type = "ping"

    f = IO.popen("ping -c 3 #{ip}")
    @output = f.readlines

    tool = Tool.find_by(tool_type: tool_type)
    tool.increment(:tool_hit_count, by = 1)
    tool.save

    return @output
  end
```

**tools/index.html.erb**

```html
<%= form_tag ping_tool_path(1), method: "post", remote: true do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :ip, params[:ip] %>
  <%= submit_tag "Ping", name: nil %>
<% end %>

<h3> Output </h3>
<p>Not AJAX: <%= @output %></p>
<div id="#output"></div>
```

**tools/ping.js.erb**

```html
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = <%= @output %>
```

**routes.rb**

```html
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'tools#index'

  resources :tools do
    member do
      #get 'ping'
      post 'ping'
    end
  end
end
```

I've confirmed that the `IO.popen(command)` is running by adding the `p @output`, which shows this in the Rails log and also successfully increases the hitcount for the tool in the DB:

```html
Started POST "/tools/1/ping" for ::1 at 2015-12-01 12:24:14 -0500
Processing by ToolsController#ping as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "ip"=>"10.10.10.1", "id"=>"1"}
["PING 10.10.10.1 (10.10.10.1): 56 data bytes"]
["PING 10.10.10.1 (10.10.10.1): 56 data bytes", "64 bytes from 10.10.10.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=2.268 ms"]
["PING 10.10.10.1 (10.10.10.1): 56 data bytes", "64 bytes from 10.10.10.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=2.268 ms", "64 bytes from 10.10.10.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=2.425 ms"]
["PING 10.10.10.1 (10.10.10.1): 56 data bytes", "64 bytes from 10.10.10.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=2.268 ms", "64 bytes from 10.10.10.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=2.425 ms", "64 bytes from 10.10.10.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=2.571 ms"]
["PING 10.10.10.1 (10.10.10.1): 56 data bytes", "64 bytes from 10.10.10.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=2.268 ms", "64 bytes from 10.10.10.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=2.425 ms", "64 bytes from 10.10.10.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=2.571 ms", ""]
["PING 10.10.10.1 (10.10.10.1): 56 data bytes", "64 bytes from 10.10.10.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=2.268 ms", "64 bytes from 10.10.10.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=2.425 ms", "64 bytes from 10.10.10.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=2.571 ms", "", "--- 10.10.10.1 ping statistics ---"]
["PING 10.10.10.1 (10.10.10.1): 56 data bytes", "64 bytes from 10.10.10.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=2.268 ms", "64 bytes from 10.10.10.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=2.425 ms", "64 bytes from 10.10.10.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=2.571 ms", "", "--- 10.10.10.1 ping statistics ---", "3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0.0% packet loss"]
["PING 10.10.10.1 (10.10.10.1): 56 data bytes", "64 bytes from 10.10.10.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=2.268 ms", "64 bytes from 10.10.10.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=2.425 ms", "64 bytes from 10.10.10.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=2.571 ms", "", "--- 10.10.10.1 ping statistics ---", "3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0.0% packet loss", "round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 2.268/2.421/2.571/0.124 ms"]
  Tool Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "tools".* FROM "tools" WHERE "tools"."tool_type" = ? LIMIT 1  [["tool_type", "ping"]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.2ms)  UPDATE "tools" SET "tool_hit_count" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "tools"."id" = ?  [["tool_hit_count", 24], ["updated_at", "2015-12-01 17:24:16.512580"], ["id", 1]]
   (7.9ms)  commit transaction
  Rendered tools/ping.js.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2034ms (Views: 3.8ms | ActiveRecord: 8.6ms)
```

My problem at this point is that nothing is showing in the view.  What am I missing?

Comment: try explicitly returning it

Comment: @Beengie the `puts` was just for debug purposes to make sure the command was actually logging something to console.

Comment: The method 'ping' has more than one variable. So I believe you must explicitly return the one you want.

Comment: @Beengie what's wrong with attempting to return the whole thing as I'm doing right now?  I should still get something in the output, regardless, right?

Comment: I will add the code so you see what i mean.

Answer (score 0):

You still will be returning the entire object. I believe you need to explicitly say which variable you want returned because there were other variables within the method. See below.

```ruby
def ping
    ip = params[:ip]
    tool_type = "ping"

    @output = []
    IO.popen("ping -c 3 #{ip}").each do |line|
      @output << line.chomp
      p @output
    end

    # this just updates the Tool hitcount in the DB
    tool = Tool.find_by(tool_type: tool_type)
    tool.increment(:tool_hit_count, by = 1)
    tool.save

    return @output # Explicitly return the variable
  end
```

You obviously want this at the end so you don't skip your `tool` events.

You don't have anything with an id of 'output' to put it in.

```
<p>Not AJAX: <span id='output'></span></p>
```

I think now you might need to pull out the span into a partial then call it with javascript.

```
# Replaces all contents...
$('#output').html("<%= j render(:partial => 'output') %>");

# Will append the contents...
$('#output').append("<%= j render(:partial => 'output') %>");
```

Then... in the views/tools folder _output.html.erb

```
= @output
```

Comment: Added the return, however still not showing in the view.  Is it possible that the AJAX is firing before the ping process is complete, therefore is showing a variable with nothing in it?

Comment: or another (I don't know AJAX) thought...  could my issue be that `@output` is in the `ping` method, whereas I'm rendering `index.html.erb`?

Comment: No, still nothing.  I think it's because I'm posting to the `ping` method in the `tools` controller, but still on the `index` view.  What do you think?  I don't know how to fix it though.

Comment: when you look at your resources, is it even loading that js.erb?

Comment: Yeah, up above, in the console log output it has `Rendered tools/ping.js.erb (0.1ms)` towards the end.